# Массив с рандомными значениями

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
data: [1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 7],
```

как создать такой же массив с рандомными значениями ?

Comment: `Math.random()`

Comment: посмотрите в базе знаний, может быть до вас кто-то [тоже задавал такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5%20%5bjavascript%5d)

Answer (score 4):

```
let randoms = [...Array(5)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 9))
```